# WooCommerce - Email admin with new user details

Tags: php, admin, woocommerce-offtopic, email

I am trying to send a custom email to the admin account when any user registers through WooCommerce. I have managed to get it to send the username `($user_login)` but have been unsuccessful in managing to provide the admin with info such as customer email and names. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

This is at the bottom of my custom `customer-new-account.php` file:

`<?php do_action( 'new_customer_registered', $user_login, $user_email ); ?>`

This is then in my `functions.php`:

```
//email admin on new customer sign up
function new_customer_registered_send_email_admin($user_login, $user_email) {
ob_start();
do_action('woocommerce_email_header', 'New customer registered');
$email_header = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();
do_action('woocommerce_email_footer');
$email_footer = ob_get_clean();

woocommerce_mail(
get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
get_bloginfo('name').' - New customer registered',
$email_header.'<p>The user '.esc_html( $user_login ).' created an account on the website.<br>Email:'.esc_html( $user_email ).'</p>'.$email_footer
);
}
add_action('new_customer_registered', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin');
```

Comment: The password can also be sent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the action needs to specify two parameters.

```
add_action('new_customer_registered', 'new_customer_registered_send_email_admin', 10, 2);
```

Apart from that I can't see any other issues...